# Some JPanels are not showing in my CardLayout Panels

Tags: java, eclipse, layout

I'm using card layout to show and hide every panel I made. For the first couple of days, it has been working fine for the first 5 panels I've made.  The weird thing is, all of a sudden, my new, 6th panel does not seem to be appearing. There is no syntax error anywhere, I went through all my codes again to look out for any typos, misspellings, failed copy pastes, but can't seem to be able to find anything out of the ordinary... I tried moving on to making the 7th panel today, but the 7th panel was not showing up either.

```
public ViewController(int width, int height){
    this.WIDTH = width;
    this.HEIGHT = height;
    bgColor = new Color(255,204,153);

    mainFrame = new JFrame ("Mei Centre");
    mainFrame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH,HEIGHT));
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout (new CardLayout(0,0));
    mainPanel.setBackground(bgColor);
    mainPanel.setVisible(true);
}

public void makePanels (){
    // make most panels
    mainPage = new MainPagePanel(this, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bgColor);
    adminLoginPage = new AdminLoginPage(this, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bgColor);
    playerLoginPage = new PlayerLoginPage(this, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bgColor);
    playerLoginPrompt = new PlayerLoginPrompt (controller, this, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bgColor);
    playerMainMenu = new PlayerMainMenu (controller, this, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bgColor);
    gameSettings = new GameSettingPanel (controller, this, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bgColor);
    dealerShuffle = new DealerShufflePanel (bgColor);

    // add panels to frame in chronological order
    mainPanel.add(mainPage, "MainPage"); // index 0
    mainPanel.add(adminLoginPage, "Admin"); // index 1
    mainPanel.add(playerLoginPage, "Player"); // index 2
    mainPanel.add(playerLoginPrompt, "LoginPlayer"); // index 3
    mainPanel.add(playerMainMenu, "PlayerMainMenu"); // index 4
    mainPanel.add(gameSettings, "GameSetting"); // index 5
    mainPanel.add(dealerShuffle, "DealerShuffle"); // index 6       

    mainFrame.add(mainPanel);

    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
}

// make and add GamePlayPanel into mainPanel
public void makeGamePanel(Dealer dealer, GameTable table, ArrayList<GamePlayerInterface> gamePlayers) {
    System.out.println("Making gamePlayPanel");
    gamePlay = new GamePlayPanel (controller, this, WIDTH, HEIGHT, bgColor, dealer, table, gamePlayers);

    mainPanel.add(gamePlay, "GamePlay"); // index 7
    mainPanel.repaint();
}
```

This is my ViewController (class that controls the main flow of my GUI). I made a main panel and set layout to CardLayout, and made all my other panels and added them into the main panel. The 7th panel was added in later, outside the constructor (inside makeGamePanel method)

```
public void showPanel(String page) {
    System.out.println("Showing panel -> " + page);
    CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(mainPanel.getLayout());
    cl.show(mainPanel, page);
}
```

This is my method used to control which panel to show. It works from panel in index 0 up to 5 (list in screenshot above)

```
private class changePanel implements ActionListener{
    String page;

    public changePanel(String page){
        this.page = page;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println(page + " is clicked");
        vController.showPanel(page);
    }
}
```

When I click on some Jbuttons in any of the panels above, I will assign this action listener with the appropriate panel name, so that it may call the method to show the appropriate panel.

```
private void startRound(GameTable table, ArrayList<GamePlayerInterface> gamePlayers, GamePlayer human) {

    // GAME START!  dealer shuffles cards
    dealer.shuffleCards();
    view.showPanel("DealerShuffle");

    /* insert some delayer here*/       
    /*does some game logic action*/

    // make game play GUI
    view.makeGamePanel(dealer, table, gamePlayers);
    view.showPanel("GamePlay");
```

My issue is with the 6th and 7th index panel (DealerShuffle, and GamePlay), which are called in my game controller (class which handles all game logic running) . 
I've checked to make sure that my controller and my view are both linked to each other, so it doesn't seem to be an issue of different instances.

```
Enter Choice --> Player is clicked.
Showing panel -> Player.
LoginPlayer is clicked.
Showing panel -> LoginPlayer.
Player Login information entered, checking information
username input got is : maggie
password input got is : joey
Showing panel -> PlayerMainMenu
Play game button clicked
Showing panel -> GameSetting
Game start button clicked!
Setting game with 1 opponents, 1 difficulty, 1 size.
Game Start
Showing panel -> DealerShuffle
Dealer deals cards onto table
Making gamePlayPanel
Game Play Panel has been created
Showing panel -> GamePlay
```

These are the results of a normal run. In the bottom few lines, it shows that my program is running properly, and that its even trying to show the DealerShuffle panel and GamePlay shuffle, but what actually happens on screen is: right as the changing panel method is called to show DealerShuffle, the previous panel (GameSettings) is actually disabled, but DealerShuffle doesn't appear, so the screen is stuck at an after-image of the GameSetting panel, with nothing for me to click on or interact with. Needless to say, my GamePlay panel afterwards wasn't showing up either.

If anybody wants to check out my whole program to run, here is the link to my zipped files: 
[Program zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/48ekpuujl342efp/Assignment%203_FishingPairsGameGUI.zip?dl=0)
The codes will be in a quite a mess, as I've only started implementing GUI on a program which was previously running off on console.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: You do not have a panel named "GamePlay", but you do have one called "GameSetting".  You should not use string literals when you create the pages and when you request which page should be displayed. You should create a String variable and use that same variable when you create the panels and when you request the page to be shown - that way you will never encounter a hard-to-find error if you ever misspell the string somewhere.

Comment: Actually I never set any dimensions for any of the panels/pages (they just fit fully onto the JFrame). Those perimeters were merely used to align my components on the panels neatly. Nevertheless, I tried your tip and gave my DealerShuffle a dimension, but that still didn't work ><

Comment: @FredK, I do have a GamePlay, its created afterwards, in the method below. And I've already double, triple, quadruple checked, but the names I've put are correct. Nevertheless, thank you for your advise, I will adopt string variables instead.

Comment: Inside of the constructor of those jpanels, do you have setVisible(true) in them?

Comment: @Orin2005 initially, no, because the visibility is to be set by the cardLayout anyway, but even when I tried changing the visibility to true in the constructors, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I may not have fixed the issue with the way my codes are currently structured or learnt what was causing the issue in the first place, but I managed to get it to work after building it from scratch again and restructuring my codes. This time instead of creating the JPanels in the viewController and adding them inside, I've build the JPanels in the Controller instead and passed them into the viewController to add to the JFrames. So anyways, problem solved. Thanks to all who helped!